# ggplot issues. Line chart not populating

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is the sample data. as currently constructed, am getting nothing displayed. the end goal is to have a line chart that displays from left to right with the various indcodes. What am I missing in order to have three lines representing the avgemp values for each indcode?

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)

 date1 <- c("2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-03-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-03-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-03-01")
 indcode <- c(7113,7113,7113,7112,7112,7112,7131,7131,7131)
 avgemp <- c(100,101,102,90,92,98,244,210,585)

 test1 <- data.frame(date1,indcode,avgemp)

 test1chart<- test1 %>% group_by(indcode) %>% ggplot(aes(x = date1, y = indcode))

 test1chart
```

Comment: `date1` in the data frame. `date` in the call to `aes()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few issues:

- `group_by` is for `dplyr`, it does nothing for `ggplot`
- name mismatch: your data has column `date1`, your plot code uses `x = date`
- What goes on the y-axis? If you want a line for each indcode, then probably `y = avgemp`, not `indcode`
- Tell `ggplot` what points to connect (this is the "group" aesthetic) `aes(group = indcode)`

```
test1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date1, y = avgemp, group = indcode)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Other changes you may want to make:

- Want to tell the lines apart? Maybe by color? Put `color = factor(indcode)` inside the `aes()`
- Have a lot of data and don't want to label every single date? Or maybe your dates are irregularly spaced? Stop treating your `date1` column as categorical by converting it to `Date` class: `test1 <- test1 %>% mutate(date1 = as.Date(date1)`